# How to trim the extra spaces or line breaks in the cognos reporting?

Tags: oracle10g, cognos, cognos-11

I have a data item where its values are  populating with some space after it.

For example the data item is State. In output the result is like ORISSA  . But after Orissa u have some space. How can I remove that space in cogons reporting for a specific data item?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try changing the data item to: Trim([State])

Answer (score 0):

*Trim* or some similar function, possibly one which is native to your DB vendor, might be helpful I think.